# Subscribe to a list of dynamic types

Tags: c#, generics, types

I use a Messenger in my program, with Subscribe and publish methods.
I would like to subscribe to a list of types of messages (which implements the interface "IMessage") for a specific object.
So, I have a method subscribe.
It should seem like this :

```
subscribe(List<T> listMessagesTypes)
{
     foreach(IMessage messageType in listMessagesTypes)
        _messenger.subscribe<messageType>(doAction);
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work

- I can nowhere define that the list shall contain only types which implement the interface IMessage
- messageType is an object, not a type. My code is grammatically wrong!

Has anyone an idea, how I can handle it?

Comment: If you want to see if it implements an interface you can test for it: `IMessage myTest = myObject as IMessage

if (myTest != null)` or simply `if(myObject is IMessage)`

Comment: I wonder why too...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to subscribe to multiple types:

```
// You need to change List<T> to List<Type>, and you need to only pass types here
public void subscribe(List<Type> listMessagesTypes)
{
    foreach(Type messageType in listMessagesTypes)
    {
        // find method "subscribe" on Messenger type
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Messenger).GetMethod("subscribe");

        // create a generic definition of method with specified type
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(messageType);

        // invoke this generic method
        // the assumption is that your method signature is like this: doAction(IMessage message)
        genericMethod.Invoke(_messenger, new object[] { new Action<IMessage>(doAction)});
    }
}
```

The method would be invoked like this:

```
var listOfTypes = new List<Type>{ typeof(MessageA), typeof(MessageB)};
subscribe(listOfTypes);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the generic subscribe method, unless its type is known at compile time.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx

You could try:

```
void subscribe(List<Type> listMessagesTypes, Action doAction)
{
   foreach (Type messageType in listMessagesTypes)         
     if (typeof(IMessage).IsAssignableFrom(messageType)
       _messenger.subscribe(messageType, doAction);
}
```

But then you would still need to implement a subscribe method that accepts a Type.